# PHP contact form with authentication and sender confirmation message. Simple and secure. How can i do it?

Tags: php, forms, forms-authentication, contacts

I need a contact form on my webpage that has some good security on it to prevent spamming, captcha or number verification. If there are form errors, I would like them displayed on the page, not on a 'confirmation' page that requires the user to hit 'back'. I would also like to have the sender have a confirmation message sent to the email address they listed.

I've had a hellish time trying a few different kinds of forms available online. Can anyone suggest resource/s to build the thing I need. I thought PHPMailer would be good, but I need some support with it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try to read this [MCVE]. We have to know where the exact problem lies. These kind of questions are too broad

Answer (score 0):

Do a thorough form validation on the front end itself using JavaScript. You'll probably find a lot of validation plugins available for free.

The captcha is generated on load, and it's checked by another server script, which you can call on clicking the submit button but before actually submitting (explore more events of form submission). This will redirect to landing page if all goes well, or aborts the submission and produces an error message.

PHP Mailer is pretty convenient fir sending emails. You can define two instances of it, one for the form submission mailing to you, and for the confirmation to sender which shall be sent when the first one is sent successfully.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you much. I appreciate your wisdom. I have little experience with JS, could you point me in a direction where I can learn some more about JS validation of PHP. I am on the road to learning them both. With the help of folks like you, I can untie the knots in my understanding of PHP and JS :)

Comment: JavaScript and PHP are different completely. The idea of using JavaScript is to manipulate and control the HTML elements (DOM basically). The JavaScript can at best check those 'input' tags of your form and test their values against a standard pattern. Some of this functionality is now available in HTML 5 specifications as some new attributes.

Comment: CodeSchool is probably a good resource to learn more about JavaScript. Once you have an idea, you can directly search for plugins etc and use them.